# C++ program hangs in vector destructor

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, destructor

I have a struct with an field which is added with a preprocessor #define:

```
struct MyType {
    int somedata;
#ifdef HAS_INDEX
    int index;
#endif
}
```

When I add instances to a vector, the program hangs when the first reallocation happens:

```
vector<MyType> myData;
myData.reserve(4);
myData.push_back(MyType{0,0});
myData.push_back(MyType{0,1});
myData.push_back(MyType{0,2});
myData.push_back(MyType{0,3});
myData.push_back(MyType{0,4}); // Program hangs
```

I set a breakpoint on the line before and then stepped through the attached process. When the old vector storage gets deallocated, the function destroying the vectors seems to get into an infinite loop at xmemory0 of the Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 compiler:

```
    // TEMPLATE FUNCTION _Destroy_range WITH ALLOC
template<class _Alloc,
class _Ptr = typename _Wrap_alloc<_Alloc>::pointer> inline
void _Destroy_range1(_Ptr _First, _Ptr _Last, _Wrap_alloc<_Alloc>& _Al, false_type)
{   // destroy [_First, _Last), no special optimization
for (; _First != _Last; ++_First) // <----- infinite loop here with _First > _Last
    _Al.destroy(_Unfancy(_First));
}
```

Why is the program hanging there?

(Question edited for clarity to show the problem)

Comment: Try providing an [mcve].  Showing a bit of effort to isolate the problem - rather than just linking to a file that contains a lot of additional code - will increase your chances of getting a useful answer.

Comment: I would be glad, if I had a minimal example which doesn't go into the compiler functions and needs an attached debugger. The relevant part is (probably) the one included in the question. And possibly I would see the problem myself, when I could reproduce it easier.

Comment: @allo *The relevant part is (probably) the one included in the question* -- Just because your program finally has an issue in the code you posted, it does not mean that this is where the real problem originated.  I would suggest using `at()` instead of `[ ]` to access your vector elements, and thus verify that you are not going out-of-bounds somewhere.

Comment: I can try it at a few places while debugging, but I mostly want to use the library. cells seems to be only increased (``.resize(cells.size()+something)``) in the code. But anyway, the real problem is at/after the return, when the vector gets destroyed.

Comment: @allo There is nothing wrong with the vector destructor.  It is exposing a problem your code created before the destructor was called.  Either you're destroying an invalid object (note that the code you posted is within a class, and if that class instance is invalid, any members declared within it are also invalid) or some other issue, such as memory corruption.

Comment: Do you see anything? I think it must be somewhere in the Body struct, when I look at the push_back example, but the struct does not contain anything unusual. The ``vec<3, real_t>`` implementation in the library has an empty constructor, the rest is STL.

Comment: Links to code dumps are not what was asked for.  Read [mcve] and come back.

Comment: The links are only for reference, the relevant part is in the question.

Comment: Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and the debugger `gdb` (notably watchpoints). *The bug is likely elsewhere.* Read more about [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: I am stepping through it with watchpoints with visual studio. Its a windows dll.

Comment: When the vector `cells` is fine before the call to `buildCells()`, and is corrupt afterwards, the problem is most likely inside `buildCells()`.

Comment: It is fine after buildCells (size=1 in the debugger). Then I get in the destructor, which destructs one element and then gets into an infinite loop. I am currently looking if somehow the ``.end()`` pointer is wrong because of buildIndex using ``Cell * child = &cells.back() - cell->numChilds + 1;`` but I do not think so.

Comment: No, it is not.  The question does not contain a MCVE.  You cannot take the code **in the question** and **compile it, run it, and get the error you are talking about**.  We don't have the definition of `Cell`s, `exafmm`, `Bodies`, the ctor to `Body`, `buildCells` etc.  You **don't know what is wrong** yet you are certain the code that causes the problem is only the code you have shown.  [MCVE] isn't just a request, it is the rule on Stack Overflow.  This is not a request for a code dump.  It is a request you read [MCVE] and do the work required to isolate the problem.

Comment: This is the 3rd time this is mentioned in the comments, I read it. I have a hard time to isolate a minimal example, as it happens in a much more complex context and I get the error when I attach a debugger to a program, which loaded the dll. So maybe read the question more about how I can debug this behaviour. I step through this and all objects seam reasonable, then in the destructor the loop seems to step over the end of the vector or something similar. And if I could reproduce it with a minimal example, I would probably be able to solve it :-/

Comment: @allo Welcome to the C++. If the code is failing at some point, it doesn't mean that's where the problem lies. It may, for example, be due to undefined behavior in an unrelated part of code. That's why we are asking for [mcve].

Comment: Yeah ... I will try to rewrite stuff since the last working version from scratch tomorrow and see if I can fix or avoid the problem.

Comment: I already solved it and reopened the question and edited it to reflect the real problem with the code to be able to self-answer this for everyone who tried to help, even when it was too hard. So no need to start flaming here. I a few minutes I will be able to accept the self-answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem after a lot of debugging.
I had a define in the struct, which added an additional member variable to the struct. 
When I built a library with the function and included the header in my program, the define was only set in one of the projects.

So the second project deleted the data in the `for (; _First != _Last; ++_First)` loop, but with a data structure which has one member more than the structure used to allocate the memory. So the loop skips over the end of the actual data. Then it gets `_Last < _First` and the loop does not terminate, because `_First` is only increased in the loop.